# Wordpress Twenty Eleven PhP - forcing php code to skip first post on homepage?

Tags: php, content, theme-twenty-eleven

[image: What I want to fix]

I have set up my Wordpress to add the [wordpress Featured Image thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)  to all posts on the homepage.

How do I make the code skip adding [wordpress Featured Image thumbnails][3] to the first post [the_content() ~ in the code below] and only add them to [wordpress Featured Image thumbnails][4] the other posts [the_excerpt() ~ in the code below]?

Code I put in content.php to make it put [wordpress Featured Image thumbnails][5] on homepage. [Link to pastebin code Here](http://pastebin.com/xWPWY5UA)

```
    <?php if ( is_search() | is_home() ) : // Edit this to show excerpts in other areas of the theme?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
    <!-- This adds the post thumbnail/featured image -->
        <div class="excerpt-thumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('excerpt-thumbnail', 'class=alignleft'); ?></a></div>
                      <?php  if($wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged()) { the_content(); } else { the_excerpt(); }     ?>                     


            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
            <?php else : ?>
            <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have edited the question but still not clear about something, let me ask it here. Do you want to show all the posts in the page except a post(you are calling it the first post)?!!

Comment: I added an image to explain.

Comment: Sorry but this didn't help either. Can you elaborate where is the first image appearing and why do you want to remove it? and where does the bottom two images appear and why do you want to keep those?

Comment: I made a code that takes the featured image (https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) assigned from each post and creates thumbnail on the homepage.

Comment: The code, however does it for all of them. I only want it for the previews at the bottom (the ones noted in orange).

Answer (score 1):

You've practically got the solution in the code ;)

Notice that the entire content of the first post is visilbe, but for the rest only the excerpt displays. That's from this (after tidying):

```
<?php 
if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { 
    the_content(); 
} else { 
    the_excerpt(); 
}
?>
```

So let's just apply that logic to the thumbnail part:

```
<?php if( $wp_query->current_post != 0 || !is_paged() ) { ?>

     <div class="excerpt-thumb">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
               <?php the_post_thumbnail('excerpt-thumbnail', 'class=alignleft'); ?>
          </a>
     </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: For some reason it kept crashing.

Comment: I haven't checked the code, but turn [debug on](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and the error message should help you fix any issues.

Comment: a small correction to the logic: `if( $wp_query->current_post != 0 || is_paged() )`